# Magento On Multi Server Architecture

Tags: magento-1.8

Recently, we have migrated your site on Amazon servers. Right now, we have a multi-server architecture having

- 1 ELB
- 2 EC2 r3.xlarge instances
- 2 RDS, one for blogs and other for Magento
- Cloudfront CDN

I am not sure if the current architecture( Implement by Certified AWS company) is perfect, but i have few issue/queries that i am curious to know

1. When we need to import a file ( inventory for e.g.) vis Data profile
   on which instance that files will be uploaded? How do Magento picks
   the files from correct instance where files are uploaded. I have
   faced issue saying file not exists when I tired to run data profile.
2. If we upload any images for a CMS pages, then will image file be
   uploaded on server first and then on CDN or directly on CDN? If the
   files are loaded on Instance first then how to CDN know on which
   instance files are uploaded?

I have tried to search on Google a lot but never got any satisfactory results.

Can anyone please provide their comments/suggestion for above.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's a training/education question for your providers, but, if they set it up correctly (normally with a batch server) it's not a problem and the CDN automatically picks up the new images and caches them from the server via NFS. Again, it all needs to be set up correctly and multi-node combined with AWS will punish you when done wrong, and reward you with increased ranking, indexing and conversions when done properly, so we outsource it all.

Comment: Do we need to have a dedicated instance for NFS?

Comment: Not necessarily, that depends on factors such as the size of catalog, scalability, security, a batch server, but you're spending $700-1,000/mth on hosting so would expect they should know what they are doing, the people we go through certainly do. Hope you're getting the performance out of it.

Comment: Can you provide me any standard architecture diagram if you have any?

Comment: https://www.nexcess.net/magento/enterprise-hosting we use something similar to their MCE-SIP200/300 but it's cloud based on Amazon AWS or Softlayer and managed by a third party.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not syncing your data between servers then you will definitely face the issues like you mention above file not exists for var or media server.

Usually, it is advisable to use a common media folder share for each server by creating a symlink to actual media server so that the issue of missing media may not come.

The file you upload from admin goes to the server which is assigned to server that particular request through load balancer. The file is first uploaded to the server and then becomes available to cloudfront.

Note: The actual implementation might be different to what it is appearing to us as per your description. You must talk to your service provider regarding the issues.I am sure they must have done something to tackle the same.